# How to send a parameter (within body, no headers) from Angular to Spring Boot?

Tags: java, angular, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

How do I send this defined parameter number from Angular/typescript to Spring Boot?

Sample fragment of **AngularJS/typescript code**, which is making a post request to the Spring Boot Microservice:

```
 login(){
    let body: any = "091" //student number
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/api/users/login", body)
    //how do I post request this "091" defined parameter to the Springboot REST URL?
  }
```

Sample fragment of **Java SpringBoot Controller** file code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api")
    public Login<String>(@RequestBody Login login{
       // ??? how do I retrieve the defined body from Angular to this Spring Boot service?
    }
```

Sample fragment of **Java SpringBoot Model** file code:

```
public class Login{
//??? What should this code look like, if it's receiving a defined parameter from Angular?
}
```

Comment: AngularJS refers to the old framework, version 1.x. After version 2.0 they renamed it to just Angular.

Comment: Instead of using the class Login, I think you can just use String

Comment: @ShamPooSham sorry i'm not sure I understand, can you please write it out to explain?

Answer (score 0):

1.Using request body

```
//Angular
login(){
    let request: any = {studentId : "091"} //student number
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/api/users/login", request)
  }

//Java Model
public class Login{
  private String studendId;//variable name should be same as the variable sent from angular
}

//Java Controller
@PostMapping(path = "/api/users/login")
 public Login<String> userLogin(@RequestBody Login login){
       System.out.println(login.studentId) //You can access the studentId using the login object
  }
```

2.Using Path variable

```
//Angular
login(){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/api/users/login/091")//append studentId in the request URL
  }

//Java Controller
@PostMapping(path = "/api/users/login/{studentId}")
 public Login<String> userLogin(@PathVariable("studentId") String studentId){
       System.out.println(studentId) //You can access the studentId variable
  }

//No need of Model class
```

Comment: i have one question! may I ask why you have changed "let body: any" to "let request: any"? Does your change still mean that the student number is sent via the body? Just wanted to make sure

Comment: @anonymousowl There is no specific reason for changing 'body' to 'request' just for better understanding i changed it, you can use 'body' itself but make sure body is an object and that object should have studentId.

Comment: oh, can you please show that as an example with "let body: any" instead? what do you mean by making sure body is an object? Sorry, using the 'let body' is a requirement, so I'm trying to understand. Thanks

Comment: Also @Manigandan, why is @ POSTmapping used in the Java controller, when Java springboot is the one simply receiving the StudentNumber from Angular?

Comment: let body: any = {studentId : "091"}; this is what i meant body as an object, and Postmapping is used in java controller to indicate which type of request is the API is of, like post,get,put,delete. In angular we are doing a post request so we have to create a post API so we are using postmapping in java controller.